# Youtube embeds not working correctly on mobile safari. Can anyone figure this out? 

Tags: css, wordpress, video, youtube

This is really strange. On my site (http://noahsdad.com/) videos I've embedded with an iframe do not always play in mobiel safari. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. It's really strange. This is not good at all since we do a daily one minute video and our entire site is almost all videos. I really need to get these videos to work.

The videos load up with a thumb nail, but when you hit play it looks like the video is trying to load, and then it just gives me a black screen and displays the youtube logo. Can't figure out.

Bouns points if you can tell me how to get the black bars to not show up on the top and bottom of the video as well. :)

Comment: @DavidFaux Sure thing. What code would you like me to past?